# How to show my pagination bootstrap inside a div in HTML, That acts in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to add pagination bootstrap to my show-posts Div, but because on my JavaScript function I Have

document.querySelector('#show-posts').innerHTML = "" - it doesn't show my bootstrap

How can I show my bootstrap pagination and also reset the innerHTML of shows-posts every time?

index.js

```
function load_posts(){
  document.querySelector('#page-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#load-profile').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#posts-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#show-posts').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#post-form').onsubmit = function() {
        compose_post();
    }
    fetch('/posts/all_posts') // url with that API
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(all_posts => {
        // Loop and show all the posts.
        console.log(all_posts)
        all_posts.forEach(function(post) { // loop to loop over each object
            build_post(post)
        });
    });
document.querySelector('#show-posts').innerHTML = ""
}
```

HTML

```
<div id ="show-posts">
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def show_posts(request):
    all_posts = NewPost.objects.all()
    all_posts = all_posts.order_by("-date_added").all()
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return JsonResponse([website_post.serialize() for website_post in page_obj], safe=False)
```

Comment: Do you want `load_posts()` to build the contents of `<ul class="pagination">`? If so, please provide an example of the data in `all_posts`, as well as an example of one of the `<a>` tags you want to generate based on that data.

Comment: Basically, I have Django on the backend ( I have added the views.py code ), and right now it seems to work that it's loading the first 5 posts, but I want to add pagination on my front end to be able to toggle between pages and load the next posts, the views.py method supposed to get the current page via request. get.GET('page') and load the posts, I'm stuck in how to add pagination in my front end to be able to toggle between pages, and currently, I can't see the bootstrap feature in my HTML if i put it inside my show-posts div, does it have to be built in the JS?

Comment: Since you're fetching the posts via JS, you have to update the navigation using JS as well.

Comment: I see, I'll check on how to paginate in JavaScript and try to make it work with my backend.